# Assembly structure in structure

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm

I want to initialize in the data segment an structure that has a structure in it

```
ROW STRUC
INDEX DB 2 DUP(?)
VALUE DB 2 DUP(?)
ROW ENDS

COLUMN STRUC
LETTER DB 2 DUP(?)
LINE ROW 26 DUP(<?,?>)
COLUMN ENDS

DATA SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'DATA'
ARRAY COLUMN <'A$',<'A$','A$'>,<'B$','B$'>,<'C$','C$'>,<'D$','D$'>,
<'E$','E$'>,<'F$','F$'>,<'G$','G$'>,<'H$','H$'>,,<'I$','I$'>,<'J$','J$'>,
<'K$','K$'>,<'L$','L$'>,<'M$','M$'>,<'N$','N$'>,<'O$','O$'>,<'P$','P$'>,
<'Q$','Q$'>,<'R$','R$'>,<'S$','S$'>,<'T$','T$'>,<'U$','U$'>,<'V$','V$'>,
<'W$','W$'>,<'X$','X$'>,<'Y$','Y$'>,<'Z$','Z$'>>
DATA ENDS
```

And I get the error

```
Error (12) Need Expression
```

Can anyoane tell me why I get this error or how can declare initialize a struc that has another struc inside it?

Comment: You got a typo here: `'H$'>,,<'I$'`

Comment: I corrected the typo and I still get the same error

Comment: What line number is the error?  There are only 11 lines in your code block, so is `12` an error code, or a line number from a different version of the code?

Comment: @PeterCordes: I get 17 rows.  @dbogdan: Then try to reduce your program until the you find the error. Does the code work if `LINE` only has 1 entry instead of 26? If so, keep adding more entries one by one. If not, you've got some syntactic error that you need to fix.

Comment: @Michael: Oh, right, for some reasons I was thinking about the struct def as one long line.  But SO code-formatting blocks don't do line-wrapping, so it's clearly not.  Anyway yeah, shrinking the test-case to 1 or 2 `ROW` members would be my suggestion, too.  This is the *minimal* in [mcve], which is a useful approach to figuring out what's wrong in general.

Comment: @PeterCordes I reduced it to so that `LINE` has only one entry, but I still get the same error. If the syntax isn't right, can you tell me how I should write it?

Comment: No, I can't, because I don't use TASM or know anything about this struct syntax.  It's all just syntactic sugar for scale factors and offsets which you could write as numeric constants anyway, but I guess if you're writing a lot of code using structs this might be even better for for readability than `bytes_per_elem = 4` or something.  Good luck getting this working; hopefully someone who knows TASM can answer.  (I'd suggest including the [mcve] version in the question, too.)